# Print a message for user while long process running in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I have a pandas operation that is taking long time because the xlsx file is pretty big to import into a dataframe. I would like to inform the user that he has to wait while the task is running but I can't manage to do it. Here is my function :

```
def create_list_of_data():
    list_data_all = []
    list_files_xlsx_f = create_list_of_xlsx()

    for xls_files in list_files_xlsx_f:        
        df = pandas.read_excel(xls_files)      
        df = df[["COL1", "COL2"]]
        list_data = df.values.tolist()
        list_data_all.extend(list_data)
    return list_data_all
```

What I tried is to use threading :

```
import itertools
import threading
import time
import sys

#here is the animation
def animate():
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        if done:
            break
        sys.stdout.write('\rloading ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\rDone!     ')


 def create_list_of_data():
    list_data_all = []
    list_files_xlsx_f = create_list_of_xlsx()

    for xls_files in list_files_xlsx_f: 
        done = False
        t = threading.Thread(target=animate)
        t.start()
        df = pandas.read_excel(xls_files)
        done = True         
        df = df[["COL1", "COL2"]]
        list_data = df.values.tolist()
        list_data_all.extend(list_data)
    return list_data_all
```

My problem is that "done" variable is not known from the animate function. Maybe it is not the right way to do that. Any ideas please?

The function create_list_of_data() is launch from a PySide button from another 
file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the boolean with an object, you can pass by reference and not by value

```
import itertools
import threading
import time
import sys

#here is the animation
def animate(holder):
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        if holder.done:
            break
        sys.stdout.write('\rloading ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\rDone!     ')

def create_list_of_data():
    list_data_all = []

    class Holder(object):
        done = False

    holder = Holder()
    t = threading.Thread(target=animate, args=(holder,))
    t.start()
    time.sleep(10) #Simulating long job
    holder.done = True         
    return list_data_all
```

I modified the example slightly so that I could run it without the extra functions.

Answer (score 1):

You should define "done" outside of the function so that it is a global variable. That way, both functions will be able to access it. Try this:

```
import itertools
import threading
import time
import sys

done = False

#here is the animation
def animate():
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        if done:
            break
        sys.stdout.write('\rloading ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\rDone!     ')


 def create_list_of_data():
    list_data_all = []
    list_files_xlsx_f = create_list_of_xlsx()

    for xls_files in list_files_xlsx_f: 
        done = False
        t = threading.Thread(target=animate)
        t.start()
        df = pandas.read_excel(xls_files)
        done = True         
        df = df[["COL1", "COL2"]]
        list_data = df.values.tolist()
        list_data_all.extend(list_data)
    return list_data_all
```

Comment: It's not working because I think "done" variable in the function and global "done" variable are not the same. It won't catch the "done = True".

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to display `loading *` while your other thread is alive:

```
import sys
import time
import itertools
import threading


def long_process():
    time.sleep(5)


thread = threading.Thread(target=long_process)
thread.start()
for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
    sys.stdout.write('\rloading ' + c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if not thread.isAlive():
        break
sys.stdout.write('\rDone!     ')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It should work but I don't manage to get return value from lon_process().

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiprocessing instead of threading and launch the functions animate and create_list_of_data in a separate process.
Something like this should work.

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp


def countdown(seconds, message):
    while seconds:
        mins, secs = divmod(int(seconds), 60)
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d} '.format(mins, secs)
        print(timeformat + message, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds -= 1

def slowFunction(seconds):
    print('Begin')
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print('Done')



q = mp.Queue()
countdownProcess = mp.Process(target=countdown, args=(10, 'loading...'))
slowProcess = mp.Process(target=slowFunction, args=(10, ))
countdownProcess.start()
slowProcess.start()
countdownProcess.join()
slowProcess.join()
```

Comment: Thanks willy1994. It will probably work but I'm not good enough (yet) to adapt your code to mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a queue to send the done value to the thread:

```
import itertools
import threading
from queue import Queue
import time
import sys

#here is the animation
def animate(q):
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        done = q.get()
        if done:
            break
        sys.stdout.write('\rloading ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\rDone!     ')


def create_list_of_data():
    list_data_all = []
    list_files_xlsx_f = create_list_of_xlsx()
    queue = Queue()

    for xls_files in range(1,1000):
        done = False
        queue.put(done)
        t = threading.Thread(target=animate, args=(queue,))
        t.start()
        df = pandas.read_excel(xls_files)
        done = True
        queue.put(done)
        df = df[["COL1", "COL2"]]
        list_data = df.values.tolist()
        list_data_all.extend(list_data)
    return list_data_all
```